# How to dynamically change value of input tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a Todo app. Although I'm able to create todos and display them but now with each todo I created a input tag which should change the name of todo.

Here is my container component index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todoItem: [],
    todoText: ""
  };
  addTodoHanlder = event => {
    let todoValue = this.state.todoText;
    this.setState({
      todoItem: [...this.state.todoItem, todoValue]
    });
    this.clearTodoText();
    todoValue = "";
  };

  clearTodoText() {
    this.setState({ todoText: "" });
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ todoText: event.target.value });
  };
  todoNameChangeHandler = event => {
    let todoVal = event.target.value;
    this.state.todoItem.map(todo => {
      this.setState({
        todoItem: todoVal
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter Todo"
          value={this.state.todoText}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.addTodoHanlder}>AddTodo</button>
        <Hello
          todos={this.state.todoItem}
          changed={this.todoNameChangeHandler}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is my Hello.js component to display todos:

```
import React from "react";

const hello = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {props.todos.map((todo,index) => {
          return (
          <div>
            <p key={index}>{todo}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} />
          </div>
  )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default hello;
```

Can someone help me out how can this be done?
I used todoNameChangeHandler  method to change the name of todos and I'm getting this error:
TypeError
props.todos.map is not a function
hello
/src/Hello.js:7:21
   4 | return (
   5 |   
   6 |

> 7 |       {props.todos.map((todo,index) => {
>        |                   ^
>      8 |         return (
>      9 |         
>     10 |           {todo}

Comment: why `todoNameChangeHandler` have loop with state; because todoItem is array which is changing to string after setState

Answer (score 0):

What happen is as soon as `todoNameChangeHandler` was called, the type of `todoItem` was changed from array to string that's why `todos.map` throws you an error.

You can change your `todoNameChangeHandler` function to something like this to just target the element you want to update.

```
todoNameChangeHandler = (event, targetIndex) => {
  let todoVal = event.target.value;
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    todoItem: prevState.todoItem.reduce(
      (accum, current, currentIndex) => {
        if (currentIndex === targetIndex) { // will look for the matching index
          return [...accum, todoVal]; // then replace the old value with the new value
        } else {
          return [...accum, current]; // otherwise just keep the old one
        }
      },
      []
    )
  }));
}
```

just make sure you pass the index of the array element from `<hello />` to `<App />`.

Comment: Hi, thank you.. this works perfectly fine.. but Could you suggest some alternative method.. I mean anything without reduce function.